# iPhone: How to connect to Windows 10 to transfer photos/videos?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, software-recommendation, data-transfer

My uncle has:

- iPhone
- iOS Version: 16.5.1 (c)
- Model Name: iPhone X

The device has a good amount of photos/videos stored.

**Question**

- What is the best approach to transfer that data to a PC Desktop with Windows 10?

It about a *software* or other solution to be able to transfer and open the files in peace in the PC Desktop.

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider iTunes as your first option?  Is there a reason you're avoiding this well established path?

Comment: The device's belong to my uncle, I have zero knowledge about iPhone, that's why I created this OP, to help him. And thanks for the suggestion. I am going to do a research about `iTunes` for `Windows 10`

Comment: @Allan - same as on Mac, iTunes doesn't import photos, though it is needed to establish trust. MS Photos can do the actual import after that. New answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need iTunes to establish trust between the devices, but iTunes does not itself import photos. For that you need Microsoft's own Photos app.

See [Apple KB - Transfer photos and videos from your iPhone or iPad to your Mac or PC](https://support.apple.com/HT201302).

> ### Import to your Windows PC
>
> You can import photos to your PC by connecting your device to your computer and using the Windows Photos
> app:
>
> 1. [Update to the latest version of iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT201352) on your PC. Importing photos to your PC requires iTunes 12.5.1 or later.
> 2. Connect your iPhone or iPad to your PC with a USB cable.
> 3. If asked, unlock your iOS or iPadOS device using your passcode.
> 4. If you see a prompt on your iOS or iPadOS device asking you to Trust This Computer, tap Trust or Allow to continue.
>
> Then visit [Microsoft’s website to find out how to import photos to
> the Windows Photos app in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/import-photos-and-videos-from-an-iphone-to-pc-2e4e4db4-4c3d-041c-b88f-3ee4358dd95e) or [Windows 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/import-photos-and-videos-from-phone-to-pc-198f2301-e9a7-c734-5f39-a8946a5ebc99).
>
> If you have turned on iCloud Photos, you’ll need to [download the
> original, full-resolution versions of your photos to your iPhone or
> iPad](https://support.apple.com/HT204055#photos) before importing them to your PC.
>
> When you import videos from your iOS or iPadOS device to your PC, some
> of them may appear the wrong way up in the Windows Photos app. You can
> add these videos to iTunes to play them in the correct orientation.
>
> If you want to ensure photos from your iOS or iPadOS device have the
> best compatibility with Windows 10 or Windows 11, try following these
> steps:
>
> 1. On your iOS or iPadOS device, open the Settings app.
> 2. Tap Camera, then tap Formats.
> 3. Tap Most Compatible. From now on, your camera will create photos and videos in JPEG and H.264 formats.

From [Microsoft Support - Import photos and videos from an iPhone to PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/import-photos-and-videos-from-an-iphone-to-pc-2e4e4db4-4c3d-041c-b88f-3ee4358dd95e)

> ### Import photos and videos from an iPhone to PC
>
> Transfer photos from an iPhone to your PC.
>
> First, connect your iPhone to a PC with a USB cable that can transfer
> files.
>
> 1. Turn your phone on and unlock it. Your PC can’t find the device if the
>    device is locked.
> 2. On your PC, select the Start  button and then select Photos to open
>    the Photos app.
> 3. Select Import > From a USB device, then follow the instructions. You
>    can pick the items you want to import and select where to save them.
>    Allow a few moments for detection and transfer.
>
> Make sure the photos you want to import are actually on the device
> rather than in the cloud. Then, follow the steps for your type of
> device.
>
> [For more info, see Import photos and videos from phone to PC](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4558756)

If your existing photos were not taken in Compatibility mode, then Photos will prompt you to download an HEIC extension from the Microsoft Store. This is required for viewing Apple's default photo file format.

Comment: Could you be agree that iCloud would be a better option? My uncle in his PC Desktop would do a login to iCloud though a Web Browser and download the files. WDYT?

Comment: It would depend on whether iCloud already has the photos, whether they'd fit in the free 5GB or you'd have to pay for extra storage...

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides free software to accomplish this transfer.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210384

It's available on the Microsoft store for Windows 10.

Comment: iTunes itself doesn't import photos, but it's needed to establish trust. MS's own Photos does the import [unless you want to manually file copy from DCIM.]

Comment: Thank you! your answer is excellent @Tetsujin

Answer (score 1):

I go with iMazing it uses the same backup as apple but also gives you the ability to view and extract files from your backup as well. just keep in mind that if the iPhone has never been backed up in a long time it will take a while.

if you just want to back up to secure the data then apples backup is sufficient just plug into windows and use iTunes. and if you want to extract the photos/vids from the photos app then you can also if its on iCloud log into iCloud and download them all from there as well. lots of options.